# RabbitMQ durable queue losing messages over STOMP

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-rabbit

I have a webpage connecting to a rabbit mq broker using javascript/websockets that are exposed by a spring app deployed in tomcat. Messages are produced 1 per second by an external application and are rendered on the webpage. The javascript subscription is durable.

[image]

The issue I'm experiencing is that when the network connection is broken on the javascript client for a period of time (say 60 seconds), the first ~24 seconds of messages are missing. I've looked through the logs of the app deployed in tomcat and the missing messages seem to be up until the following log statement:

```
org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - DEBUG - TCP connection to broker closed in session 14
```

I think this is the point at which the endpoint realises the javascript client is disconnected and decides to close the connection to the broker resulting in future messages queueing up.

My question is how can I ensure that the messages between the time the network is severed and the time the endpoint realises the client is disconnected are not lost? Should the endpoint put the messages back on the queue somehow? Maybe there's a way to make it transactional?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Tomcat application should not acknowledge messages from RabbitMQ until it confirms that your Javascript client has received them. This way, any messages that aren't ack-ed by the JS client won't be ack-ed by Tomcat, and RabbitMQ will re-deliver them.

I don't know how your JS app and Tomcat interact, but you may have to implement your own ack process there.